# Getting Index of selected row in PyQT5/ Pyside2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyqt5

I am trying to select a row, get the index of the row, and return the values of the cells in that row.

I am trying to get the selected test into the Qlineedit line at the bottom.

Here is what I have so far

[image]

Here is what I would like to do

[image]

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, Slot
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QHeaderView, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
                               QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem,
                               QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTableView, QGridLayout, QGroupBox)
from PyQt5 import  uic
#from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView as Qtv
import pandas as pd
from PandasModel import PandasModel
from openpyxl import load_workbook


class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):        
        super(Widget, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('Test1.ui', self) # Load the .ui file
       
        
        ## Items 
        self.items = 0
        
        #Reading Data with Pandas. 
        #self._data = pd.read_excel('dataE.xlsx')
        self._data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
        ## Writing with openpyxl to edit.
        self.wb = load_workbook(filename = 'dataE.xlsx')
        self.ws = self.wb['Sheet1']     
       
        #######UI Build #######
        self.table = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QTableView, 'tableView')
        
        
        
         ###### Left
        # self.table = QTableView(self)       
        
        self.model = PandasModel(self._data)
        
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
         
   
       
        

        
        
        ### Do Not Comment Out Below.##########

        ######### Signals and Slots
        self.addNewBtn.clicked.connect(self.add_element)
        # self.quit.clicked.connect(self.quit_application)
        # self.clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_table)
        # self.alarmNote.textChanged[str].connect(self.check_disable)
        # self.assetID.textChanged[str].connect(self.check_disable)
    
        ## Filter area
        self.filter_proxy_model = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.filter_proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.filter_proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(0) # First column
        self.searchLine.textChanged.connect(self.filter_proxy_model.setFilterRegExp)
        self.table.setModel(self.filter_proxy_model)
        
        ### Select Whole row if click on item.
        #self.selected = self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        
        #### TEST AREA FOR SELECTION ####
        self.table.clicked.connect(self.add_element)
        
        
        
    @Slot()
    def add_element(self, index):
        datas = index.data()
        #datas = str(self._data.loc(self.selected))
        self.alarmGen.setText(datas)
       
        #print(self._data.iloc[[0], [0,1,2]])
        
        
    
        
    @Slot()
    def quit_application(self):
        QApplication.quit()


    @Slot()
    def clear_table(self):
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        self.items = 0   
        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Alpha Notation Tool")

        # Menu
        # self.menu = self.menuBar()
        # self.file_menu = self.menu.addMenu("File")

        # Exit QAction
        exit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
        exit_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        exit_action.triggered.connect(self.exit_app)

        # self.file_menu.addAction(exit_action)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    @Slot()
    def exit_app(self, checked):
        QApplication.quit()        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Qt Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # QWidget
    widget = Widget()
    # QMainWindow using QWidget as central widget
    window = MainWindow(widget)
    #window = uic.loadUi("Test1.ui")
    window.resize(906, 600)
    window.show()

    # Execute application
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think you would get more help if you narrow the problem a little bit

Answer (score 0):

To select a row instead of  single cell when you click on a cell in the table you could set the selection behaviour of the table view to `QAbstractItemView.selectRows` using

```
self.table.setSelectionBehavior(self.table.SelectRows)
```

You might also want to set `self.table.setSelectionMode(self.table.SingleSelection)` if you only want to select one row at the time.

To set the text of your line edit to a space-separated string of the data in the currently selected indices you could do something like

```
data = (index.model().data(index, role=Qt.DisplayRole) for index in self.table.selectedIndexes())
self.line_edit.setText(' '.join(data))
```

To automatically update the text in the line edit when the selection in the table has changed you could connect the signal `self.table.selectionModel().selectionChanged` to an appropriate slot.